# Проблемы с подключением библиотек Qt C++

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Только недавно начал изучать qt, но проблема в том, что он не находить библиотек. Ругается в пресловутом hello world'идке, который я взял из книги "Qt5.3. Профиссиональное программирование на C++" Макса Шлее, на то, что не находит QtWidgets. Пробовал другие варианты с QtGui и QApplication, но все тоже самое. Более чем уверен, что проблема валяется где то на поверхности, но мозгов, что бы дойти до ее решения, у меня не хватает. Есть идеи куда копать?

Лист пакетов, которые у меня поставленны, может в этом дело  : qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools qtcreator build-essential libfontconfig1 mesa-common-dev

Comment: Как именно ругается?

Comment: Мол, не находит файла или каталога. Положим, подключаю, #include <QtWidgets>, говорит, что нет такого

Comment: Используйте qmake/cmake в качестве системы сборки и все проблемы уйдут.

Answer (score 1):

Открой свой проект в QtCreator и зайди в файл НАЗВАНИЕПРОЕКТА.pro. в нем найди строчку "QT       +=". Она должна выглядеть так:

```
QT       += core widgets gui
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]